# Match performance times with audience availability using MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked at a lot of the stackoverflow answers around this subject, but they all seem to be coming at it from a different direction. Here's what I want to do, and at this stage I'm more head-scratching as to the way to approach it than writing the specific code.

The task is to display shows that a user could see based on their existing commitments, whether that be not available or already seeing something else.

Table A contains a list of start & end times of user unavailability

Table B contains a list of start & end times of user existing bookings.

Table C contains a list of start & end times of all shows.

To add more detail to this, I'm using FullCalendar agendaView to display a users commitments. In the gaps I want to display shows they could see. The code to display the unavailability and existing commitments is already written, but I have no clue now trying to find shows in Table C that don't clash with entries in Tables A & B.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is for PHP, but I'm sure there is a better solution hiding in an SQL stored procedure or something.

If you work with Unix Time you can simply test for open slots by comparing begin and end times:

1. Dynamically create a list of available slots for a user.
2. Iterate through this list and compare an open slot with each show in Table C. Something like

   ```
   if (
          (showtime['begin'] >> opentime['begin']) &&
          (showtime['end'] << opentime['end'])
      ) return true;
   ```
3. If you find a match, print it out.

EDIT:

After thinking a bit I came up with possibly a better solution. There is no way to get away from *not* comparing everything item by item. So the trick is to instead of doing all the processing at once, spread it out over the entire lifecycle of the app:

- Edit the database and add duration field to all the tables.
- Make a stored procedure (mySQL can do this, right?) that triggers on a table update. This procedure calculates the duration and fills the corresponding field for that tuple.
- Now you select all the tuples whose duration =< some open slot

This way all the grunt work is done in SQL and not in PHP, so it could be faster.

Comment: Also, this question should probably be tagged with `homework`

Comment: I did think about that approach - but the number of shows in Table C are potentially going to be a big number, so iterating through rather than doing something clever with a select statement seems mighty inefficient.

Comment: Part of the problem is being able to identify those gaps that exist between other shows and availability, so one thing I have considered doing is writing all those times into an array, sort the array by start times and then iterate through that to find shows in Table C that fit.